# audio not playing through headphones

Tags: sound, 14.04

I am using Dell Alienware M14X. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. The problem that I am facing is that the audio plays only through speakers all the time even I though I plug in my headphone.

When I go to sound settings, it is showing me headphones in the *"play sound through"* which means that my system is able to detect the headphones; But just the audio doesn't play through the headphones, instead it still plays through speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command into the Terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Scroll down and add these lines to the end of the file:

```
#Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-amic
```

Then, save , reboot and test sound using headphones and speakers.

Comment: Hi Tharindu. I did whatever you have said but with no luck. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Okay, then go back to the previous method and remove the lines added by you, and press Alt+Ctrl+T to open up the terminal and type `alsamixer` and hit Enter. You'll be greeted with a semi-UI that looks much like a mixer (imagine that!). Chances are, you will see a muted channel somewhere in that. Use the left and right arrow keys to highlight the muted channel, and press the M key to unmute it.

Comment: Thanks man. HP/Speakers auto detect was off in alsamixer. I turned it on and boom!! the audio started coming through my headphones.

Comment: I also have the Alienware. When bringing up `alsamixer` I enabled the HP/Speakers. But I can not change the volume from 00