# Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth headphones play through internal speakers

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm trying to pair my Skullcandy Crusher Wireless headphones to my computer. I'm able to get them paired, and selected in the sound menu successfully, but for some reason audio still plays through the internal speakers?

I tried the fixes described in [477933](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477933/audio-not-playing-through-headphones), and https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/ to no avail

This is what my settings menu looks like:
[image: settings img]
Which is wierd because it looks like both the output and the input are hooked together, but I never set them that way?

Does anybody know how to fix this?

### Edit

Here are the printouts from the dmesg commands in the tutorial from above

```
(base) aaron@aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth # Shows all Bluetooth driver info
[    3.163206] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.163223] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.163231] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.163233] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.163235] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.216419] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 0 week 11 2017
[    3.217429] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    3.217430] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.217430] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.217431] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.217431] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.217432] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.218922] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-32-1.sfi
[    4.876884] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.877409] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1623682 usecs
[    4.877453] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.891412] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 13645 usecs
[    4.891818] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-32-1.ddc
[    4.892417] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
[    5.114099] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.114101] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.114104] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.193395] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.193409] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.193416] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
(base) aaron@aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth | grep -i firmware # Shows Bluetooth firmware issues
[    3.217432] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.218922] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-32-1.sfi
[    4.876884] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.877409] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1623682 usecs
(base) aaron@aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch:~$ lsusb # Displays hardware connected to the USB ports
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:56b2 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:245a Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(base) aaron@aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch:~$
```

When I went into the `alsamixer` it showed my headphones were, muted, so I unmuted them, as the SO question above indicated, but that didn't help things either.

### Update

Okay, I'm working through the [Sound Troublshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) and have found a couple things to note.

1. When I execute

```
pacmd
>>> list-sinks
>>> exit
```

It lists the bluetooth headphones as a sink, but upon exiting, my bluetooth system crashes, and I have to reboot my headphones to get them to reconnect. Here is the output from the command:

```
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB,   front-right: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC257 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6001110000 irq 142"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "34c8"
        device.product.name = "Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
  * index: 1
    name: <bluez_sink.38_F3_2E_BA_F6_B6.a2dp_sink>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 45.32 ms
    card: 1 <bluez_card.38_F3_2E_BA_F6_B6>
    module: 23
    properties:
        bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "Crusher Wireless"
        device.string = "38:F3:2E:BA:F6:B6"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_38_F3_2E_BA_F6_B6"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Crusher Wireless"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    active port: <headset-output>
```

Note that the headphones are not muted, and the output volume is at 100%

2. When I execute `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` THE SOUND COMES OUT OF THE HEADPHONES! But if I go back to the settings menu and try to `test` the speakers, or if I play music through Firefox, the sound comes out of the internal speakers, still.
3. The rest of the steps came out normal, except I noted that when I use `aplay -l` my list doesn't include the headphones as an audio sink, which might be important? I don't know.

Here is the outputs from the corresponding commands for the guide:

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`find /lib/modules/`uname -r `| grep snd`

```
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/synth/snd-util-mem.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/synth/emux/snd-emux-synth.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-es1968.ko
...
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-lib.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/opl3/snd-opl3-synth.ko
```

The full output can be found here: https://pastebin.com/6dXhsa8h

`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 142
    Memory at 6001110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6001000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

### Update

As per request, here are the outputs from the specified steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257974/sound-not-working-focal-fossa-ubuntu-20-04/1261044#1261044)

1.1 `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x6001110000 irq 142
```

1.2 `lsmod | grep snd`

```
snd_sof_pci            20480  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    69632  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_sof               106496  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core          245760  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_realtek   122880  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

1.4 `inxi -SA`

```
System:    Host: aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Smart Sound Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic
```

1.5 `lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio`

```
55:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:34c8] (rev 30)
56: Subsystem: Lenovo Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [17aa:3821]
57- Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
58- Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
59-00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller [8086:34a3] (rev 30)
60- Subsystem: Lenovo Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller [17aa:3804]
```

1.6 `uname -a`

```
Linux aaron-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-15IILTouch 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1.7 `aplay -l` See previous update
1.8 `sudo lshw -C multimedia`

```
  *-usb:2
       description: Video
       product: Integrated Camera
       vendor: SunplusIT Inc
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 17.11
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:142 memory:6001110000-6001113fff memory:6001000000-60010fffff
```

1.9 `dpkg -l | grep alsa`

```
ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                      all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

1.10 `dpkg -l | grep linux- | grep $(uname -r)`

```
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic             5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic               5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic             5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic       5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, and if it fixes my issue, I'll close the question

Comment: Correction, this is for 20.04, I will correct the title

Comment: Output going to the wrong device is pretty odd, no idea what's happening there. The input device is likely a bluetooth microphone on the headset. Have you already looked over the (extremely outdated) resources at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting?

Comment: I will do that, thank you, I forgot that existed

Comment: Even if you perhaps do not have a driver issue, it may be useful to post the output of items
1.1, 
1.2, 
1.4, 
1.5, 
1.6, 
1.7, 
1.8, 
1.9, 
from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261044/226614).
If you want to check the rest of the items as well, it can't hurt.
With that I might be able to come up with an answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll get on that after class today

Comment: @Christian I added notes from following the troubleshooting guide

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I have added the requested information

Comment: [option # 3 here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640) might help or rule out issues related to pulseaudio configuration.

Comment: @Raffa That Worked! If you make that an answer, I will accpet it and reward you the  bounty

Comment: @iggy12345 I am glad it worked and answer added as you requested. Stay healthy

Comment: @Raffa I'll assign the bounty once the grace period is over, thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first suggest rebuilding new **pulseaudio** configuration for your user account. This might, in many cases, fix the problem or at least rule out issues related to pulseaudio configuration.

Old `pulseaudio` configuration files can sometimes conflict with newer versions of `pulseaudio` after package upgrades. To fix this please follow the steps below:

- Back up `~/.config/pulse/` configuration directory to `~/.config/pulse_old/` by running the following command in the terminal:

  `mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/`
- After that, please reboot your system to build new `pulseaudio` configuration files. A new `~/.config/pulse/` directory will be created automatically.
- Test your audio now.

If, somehow, **after applying this fix** you decide to go back to the previous state before applying the fix, please follow the steps below:

1. Run the following command in the terminal:

   `rm -r  ~/.config/pulse/`
2. Run the following command in the terminal:

   `mv  ~/.config/pulse_old/ ~/.config/pulse/`
3. Reboot your system.

However, **if all is okay and the problem is fixed**, you can remove the backed up old configuration directory `~/.config/pulse_old/` to free space ( if you wish ) by running the following command in the terminal:

```
rm -r  ~/.config/pulse_old/
```

Comment: I wonder if rebooting is really the only way to refresh it

Comment: @matanster No `pulseaudio -k` will refresh it as well. But rebooting will reload everything that is related to audio like alsa and bluetooth related modules and services and will make sure the new configuration files take effect the right way.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem once, both in *Windows* and *Linux*, and the solution in both systems was to **disable the headset microphone** (choose internal microphone).

It seems [(discussion here)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1004712/195571) that the bluetooth interface supports only one of these

- High quality (a2dp) audio output, OR
- High quality (a2dp) microphone input, OR
- Low quality (hsp/hfp) input and output.

It might be the case that your headset microphone is capturing with high quality, thus it blocks your headset speakers.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work

Comment: This answer is also correct, though, it was not the original issue I was having. But it is also important to note

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04, I would recommend to **replace** `Pulseaudio` with `Pipewire`. It will work with all your apps, because it aims to replace both PulseAudio and JACK, by providing a PulseAudio-compatible server implementation and ABI-compatible libraries for JACK clients..

I run Ubuntu 20.04.3 and Pipewire runs very stable so far. My bluetooth headset works with Microsoft Teams now. In my case I run Bitwig, Spotify, Youtube etc. at the same time and it just works with every output device (Bluetooth Headset, RME Audio Interface, internal speakers).

I post the link for the installation steps, which worked for me: [Replacing Pulseaudio with Pipewire in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339765/replacing-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-in-ubuntu-20-04)