# no audio from headset after switching from a2dp to hsp/hfp 20.10 intel wireless ax200

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, iwlwifi, 20.10

I use (k)ubuntu to work, and now that I have to use video call applications daily, I've noticed the subpar quality of my integrated mic. I know my bluetooth headset works as a headset because I've used it on my phone as a bluetooth headset, and it even shows up in the volume mixer as a headset. When I connect the headset to my pc, I can use a2dp(stereo playback), but cannot use my microphone. When I try to switch to hsp/hfp in pulseaudiovolumecontrol, I can hear my own voice echoing in my headset, but can no longer hear anything from my pc. However, I can see in my volume manager that the microphone is now available(although it doesn't work). here are some details on my hardware:

my wifi/bt card according to lspci:

```
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

PACMD output:

```
    index: 2
        name: <bluez_card.FC_58_FA_C4_9D_17>
        driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
        owner module: 28
        properties:
                device.description = "JLab BT"
                device.string = "FC:58:FA:C4:9D:17"
                device.api = "bluez"
                device.class = "sound"
                device.bus = "bluetooth"
                device.form_factor = "headset"
                bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_58_FA_C4_9D_17"
                bluez.class = "0x260404"
                bluez.alias = "JLab BT"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
                device.intended_roles = "phone"
        profiles:
                headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
                a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 40, available: yes)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
        active profile: <a2dp_sink>
        sinks:
                bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_C4_9D_17.a2dp_sink/#8: JLab BT
        sources:
                bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_C4_9D_17.a2dp_sink.monitor/#12: Monitor of JLab BT
        ports:
                headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:

                headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
```

Also now looking at my journal for bluetooth-related errors I see some lines that raise questions:

```
Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Failed to release transport 

/org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_58_FA_C4_9D_17/sep1/fd7: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist

Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
```

Update: I tried to update to groovy gorilla, as I thought that it may remedy my issue as stated in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1871794
but it didn't work out, so I've updated the title to 20.10

Comment: I would suggest you try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272433/968501) and see if it helps.

Comment: Iti didn't work sorry, same result as before, I did get this new line in my system log from bluetoothd though: `Control: Refusing unexpected connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so an update to bluez and the audio stack that fixes this just came out today(23 november 2020). All one needs to do to apply the fix is:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` and your wireless ax200 card should accept hsf/hfp. Note that I'm doing this on groovy gorilla, I am unsure of any support for this in lts versions(but if you do the above step and this dosen't work, you should try using `do-release-upgrade`). NOTE: the audio is very low quality for the hfp profile, I've made a switcher based on another script, and my switcher is available [here](https://gist.github.com/JakeTrock/6158cb81117605d75603fa637e72fd66)
for all interested parties who want to be able to use push-to talk. Just put your headphone's mac address in the textbox and toggle with the button